lines on Blenderkit materials
I've tried adding many different metal materials from Blenderkit to this part, and they all end up with a darker area that looks like a shadow, but stays in the same place no matter where the light is. 

Do you have inverted face normals there?

Just tried that, no luck

Or duplicate geometry in any way? Well, just from the pure image without any information about your mesh, face normals or any other possible things that might be going on in your scene it is hardly answerable where this comes from. Maybe you could upload your file here and follow the instructions to edit it into your scene: https://blend-exchange.com

Gordon, thanks for the response. I tried uploading but I can't get it down to 30mb. The file was imported as an .STL, so I think that's the issue. I tried modelling it in Blender and didn't have the issue. I'd like to get the original file to work though.
